# Inserting ISODate field using mgo error

Tags: go, mgo

I'm really new in using go, mgo and gin gonic ...I've been creating a mini app and I have a problem inserting a new register into mongoDB using mgo. My error says:

> "PANIC: error parsing element 0 of field documents :: caused by ::
>   wrong type for '0' field, expected object, found 0: [ { date: new
>   Date(1441051152939), from: "11", to: "12", office: "2", client_id:
>   "1368465545" } ]_"

My struct is the next one:

```
type Reservation struct {
      ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id"`
      Date      time.Time     `bson:"date" json:"date"`
      From      string        `bson:"from" json:"from"`
      To        string        `json:"to"`
      Office     string       `json:"office"`
      Client_id string        `json:"client_id"` }
```

And I'm trying to insert it as follows using gin-gonic and mgo:

```
    func addReservation(c *gin.Context) {

          x := session.DB("projXXXX").C("reservation")
          var reservations []Reservation
          c.Bind(&reservations)>             
          err := x.Insert(&reservations)
          if err != nil {
                panic(err)
          }
          c.String(200,"whatever")  
}
```

My collection in mongoDB is like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ba2e611cb87b9a6d75e94b"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-10-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "from" : "9",
    "to" : "10",
    "office" : "4",
    "client_id" : "1123456469797"
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Try to catch error from `c.Bind()` call and print it to the screen. Probably there is an error, and reservations are empty, thus Insert() is failing. Also, why some of the fields have 'bson' tag, and others don't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the look of the error, MongoDB is seeing an array where it expects to see a single object.  It looks like the problem is that you're trying to insert the `[]Reservation` slice as a single object.

Rather than taking a slice of objects to insert, [`Collection.Insert`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Insert) takes each object to insert as a separate argument.  You probably want to use [the special `...` syntax for calling a variadic function](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

```
err := x.Insert(reservations...)
```

Comment: yes Im trying to insert multiple objects at a time..I tried inserting one at a time using a foreach and it works...something like this :                        for _, reserv := range reservations {
           err := x.Insert(&Reservation{Date: reserv.Date, From: reserv.From, To: reserv.To, Office: reserv.Office, Client_id: reserv.Client_id})             
            if err != nil {
                  panic(err)
            }
       }

Comment: You should be able to do it with a single call to Insert(), as I suggest in the answer.  The `...` syntax calls the method as if each element of the slice was passed as a separate argument.

Comment: the above is not working for me throwing error like `insert.documents.0' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'`